# Declaring functions with parameters inside a namespace

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

enter code hereenter code here`Im trying to create a namespace called RATING in which it has two functions in it, called "create" and "addHandler".
But the create function receives a selector as an argument. The selector points to "div" tag, and the The addHandler function receives a "a" element as an argument.

How can I make this?

```
;RATER = {
    name: 'RATER',

    create: function($){
        $(".stars")
    }(jQuery);,

    addHandler: function(){

    }(jQuery);
}
```

This is what I have tried, I know its wrong but Im not sure how to do it.

Comment: So, what is the problem and what have you tried, show us your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this

**HTML:**

```
<div id='d'>Div</div>
<a id="link" href='http://heera.it'>Link</a>
```

**JS:**

```
var RATING = {};
RATING.name = 'Rater';
RATING.create = function(selector){
    alert('Name : ' + this.name); // <-- this.name = RATING.name
    $(selector).css('color', 'red');
};

RATING.addHandler = function(aTag){
    $(aTag).on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('href : ' + this.href);
    });
};
```

Use it like

```
$(function(){
    RATING.create('#d');
    RATING.addHandler($('#link'));
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/C9jZU/1/)

Comment: Yes your answer is very helpful but how can I make the selector point to 'div' tag (in this case, the div has class called stars)?